# Selection and modifying inside Shape word

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I created A macro to select a specific shape and select Text inside him and look for a specific word and change it 
but It keep showing me an error  for `selection.find`
this is my code

```
wrdDoc.Shapes("Groupe 643").Select
wrdDoc.Shapes("Groupe 643").GroupItems("Text 
Box644").TextFrame.TextRange.Select
With Selection.Find
  .Text = "Frame FME"
  .Replacement.Text = Sheets("Generate").Range("B67")
 .Forward = True
 .ClearFormatting
 .Wrap = wdFindContinue
.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

Any suggestions 
Thank you in advance

Comment: `Selection.Find` is currently working on the Excel application's `Selection` object.  Is that what you intended?  I'm not very familiar with the Word object model, but should it be `wrdDoc.Selection.Find`?

Comment: Nop,  I did tested it but it shows me this error "methode  ou propriété n'est pas gérer par cet objet"  it is excel vba controlling word doc the macro when I run it...  It select the text inside the shape but with that selection I can't do anything ...  Problem with selection.find

Comment: If it isn't `wrdDoc.Selection.Find` then `Selection` might be a property of the Word application object.  (You haven't posted enough code for us to see what you have called that object, so you will have to determine that yourself.)  It is **definitely** not appropriate to use the **Excel** `Selection` object if you are trying to use whatever you selected in Word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't try to use the Selection object at all. Instead, you can get at the `Text` in the shape and use the `Replace` function to modify it.

```
With ActiveDocument.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange
    Debug.Print .Text
    .Text = Replace(.Text, "text", "new text")
    Debug.Print .Text
End With
```

Comment: I didn't even stop to think, when I was making my comments to the question, that we could avoid thinking about which Word object hosted `Selection` by simply getting rid of its use!  Doh!!!